# Ruby on Rails 3: Updating join table, using 2 parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, where-clause

I have a join table, which have 3 parameters. I want to update it, using a where-clause, something like this: (which obviously is not correct)

```
Grid.update(:page_id => @page_id,:thing_id => @thing_id,:number => @number ).where(:page_id => @page_id, :number => @number ).first
```

I need to find the record with mathing page_id and number, and then update the thing_id.

Thanks! 
Jakob

Comment: The old and new number/page are equal?

Answer (score 0):

```
Grid.where(:page_id => @page_id, :number => @number).first.
  update_attributes(:page_id => ...,: thing_id => ..., :number => ...)
```

Comment: Thanks! also this works: 

    Grid.where(:page_id => @page_id, :number => @number).update_all(:thing_id => @thing_id)


Found the example here: 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/

Comment: @jakobk: indeed. Actually you can write everything in update_all (see the conditions argument). Personally I wouldn't do it because it does not fit semantically your intent (that's subjective, of course)